# Json Deserialization with same property name with different case

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I want to understand how Json.NET deserializes a JSON object to corresponding c# object when we have multiple property names with different cases(I know this is not a good practice, but just curious to know how JSON.NET deals with this).

I have a c# object defined as below:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmployee { get; set; }
}
```

And json object as

```
{ "Name": "TestName","Isemployee":true, "isemployee":false};
```

Then, if I use the JSON.NET de-serialize method to convert above json string to TestModel object, which one of those two properties will be assigned to `IsEmployee` variable? And why?

Thanks.

Comment: Isemployee and isemployee is not the same what IsEmployee, so IsEmployee will be false, because it's the default bool value

Comment: No, if I give isemploye as true, it's parsing as true.

Comment: According to [this](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/03/21/json-net-3-5-beta-3-jsonserializer-improvements) very old "release note", *Json.NET* attempts a case insensitive match if the exact match fails. Not sure if this functionality is configurable or even still valid, but from what you are describing it seems to be. Try to change the order of `Isemployee` and `isemployee` to find out if it has any impact on the applied `IsEmployee` value. My guess is that the last element takes precedence.

Comment: Hi,  if I change the order, it's taking value of last property.

Comment: OK. I took the liberty of summarizing this in an answer, please see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In deserialization, *Json.NET* attempts case insensitive matching of an attribute if exact matching fails, as discussed [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/03/21/json-net-3-5-beta-3-jsonserializer-improvements). This is in contrast to the built-in .NET JSON serializers, see [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm).

If multiple matches are detected, the last match takes precedence.